# Doing a regular expression in JavaScript to match between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression in JS that matches between two characters but there can be like two different variations so it needs to know that.  I need to match between comma and (, OR comma and letter followed by a period. ("T.")

Here's the data I have:

```
Doe, John (SUP)
Doe, John T. (SUP)
Doe, John Smith (SUP)
Doe, John Smith T. (SUP)
Doe, John-Smith (SUP)
Doe, John-Smith T. (SUP)
```

I need to match just the first name from that.  So it would be like this:

```
John
John
John Smith
John Smith
John-Smith
John-Smith
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var nameLinkAdd = nameLink.match(/\,(.*?)\(/g);
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: You can start by splitting them per line

Comment: BTW guys, it'll only be one line each time.  I just gave all the different possibilities (at least I think all the possibilities).  But it'll just be one name at a time that's going to be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you don't necessarily have the `(SUP)` after. Ie it would work on

```
Doe, John
Doe, John-Smith

nameLink.match(/\, *([A-Za-z]+(?:[- ]+[A-Za-z]+\b(?!\.))*)/)'
```

The `(?!.)` makes sure you don't capture anything followed by a peroid `.`.

If you want to avoid lookarounds (could be a speed issue, although with such short strings I don't think so), try:

```
nameLink.match(/\, *([A-Z][a-z]+(?:[- ]+[A-Z][a-z]+)*)/)'
```

However this assumes that all names have more than one letter, and start with one capital followed by lowercase (which seems reasonable, are there any names with internal uppercase letters or names consisting of just one letter?)

Comment: I think that's safe to assume.  I don't think there are one letter names or anything weird like that.  With your regex, it selects that comma and space too.  like ", John". Was it not doing that for you?

Comment: It *matches* the comma but the name itself is in group 1 (the first set of capturing brackets).

Answer (score 0):

I like to use http://regexpal.com/ to work out a regular expression.

Comment: I use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ which is a really solid tool, but regex, especially more complex ones, just have my mind scrambling all over the place and eventually I just hit a bump and can't continue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nameLink.match(/^(\w+(?:\s*\w+)*)\s+(?:\w\. )?\()/);
```

What you want will be in group 1.

`normal* (special normal*)*` again ;)

- normal = `\w`
- special = `\s*`

Comment: That still catches the 'T' in the above.